# forum post editor problem Wysiwyg

Tags: 7, nodes

hello i have my local server setup and everything works great so i migrate from local to webservever

then something stop working.

My permissions in some way resetted and the problem is that even when i have enable and all correct permissions the editor not working.. i cannot even see enable-disable rich text

also overlay not working something happen and stopped.

But the main problem is the tinymce not working even when setup it correct from my local server (i see the setting side by side and choose them) but i again doesnt work any thoughts.

Comment: Found answer, in administrator -> configuration at performance section i disable Aggregate JavaScript files which i had enabled, so i realize that i had a problem in my js code so i need to check it up, but after i disable it everything works perfect.

Comment: so pls close this quesiton ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answered in comment by Dimitris B:**

Found answer, in administrator -> configuration at performance section i disable Aggregate JavaScript files which i had enabled, so i realize that i had a problem in my js code so i need to check it up, but after i disable it everything works perfect.